# UITableView custom section header appears below the cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios

I've a custom section header in my UITableView and I can't figure out why they are appearing bellow the UITableViewCell of the table. See the screenshots:

[image: UITableViewCell are above the section header]

This is the code that creates the section header:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [LojaInfoHeaderView lojaInfoHeaderForSection:section withTitle:sectionTitle opened:[self sectionIsOpen:section] andDelegate:self];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [LojaInfoHeaderView viewHeight];
}
```

And the section's cell are inserted or deleted when the user touches the section header:

```
- (void)lojaInfoHeader:(LojaInfoHeaderView *)lojaInfoHeader sectionDidOpen:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *indexPathsToInsert = [self indexPathsForSection:section];
    [self setSection:section open:YES];
    [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}

- (void)lojaInfoHeader:(LojaInfoHeaderView *)lojaInfoHeader sectionDidClose:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *indexPathsToDelete = [self indexPathsForSection:section];
    [self setSection:section open:NO];
    [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];    
}
```

How can I make the section header appears above the cells? How to fix it?

**Update to show how things are created**

These are the class methods I'm using:

```
+ (CGFloat)viewHeight {
    return 44.0;
}

+ (LojaInfoHeaderView *)lojaInfoHeaderForSection:(NSInteger)section withTitle:(NSString *)title opened:(BOOL)isOpen andDelegate:(id<LojaInfoHeaderDelegate>)delegate {
    LojaInfoHeaderView *newHeader = [[[LojaInfoHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)] autorelease];
    newHeader.section = section;
    [newHeader setTitle:title];
    newHeader.delegate = delegate;
    [newHeader setOpen:isOpen animated:NO];
    return newHeader;
}
```

Comment: Are you positive that `[LojaInfoHeaderView viewHeight]` is actually returning the correct height and not returning 0?

Comment: Yes, the implementation is + (CGFloat)viewHeight { return 44.0; } // and 44 is the correct height.

Comment: Off topic: how are you getting the nav bar and toolbar and all the bar buttons to have that lovely purple color? Are you running under iOS 4.x? Thanks. (Not sure of best way to get response - short of posting question directed to you.)

Comment: It's a navigation bar tint color

Comment: thanks. does that override "Done" button and others that get the 'special' aqua blue color?

Comment: Yes, it tints all standard bar buttons in the same color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was setting the backgroundColor using alpha (yeah, I can't believe I miss this).

Wrong code in initWithFrame:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.1];
```

Correct code:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.89 green:0.89 blue:0.89 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: well, this one could be hard to guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your whole table style to be grouped instead of plain. Or change your section view to be opaque. Whatever is the design requirement.

Comment: Setting self.opaque = YES in initWithFrame didn't solve. As of using grouped style I can't see why this would be a solution because the design matters, and it makes the section header not stick which isn't what I need.

Comment: you can try to set it as a table header view, not section header view, may be this will solve it.

Comment: Could be, but I've more than one section and in the screenshot I'm showing just one. But this problem happens with all the sections.

Comment: I see your functions are class functions, not of the instance of the class, can you post some more code on how you create your section header? It will help to better understand the creation process

Comment: thanks, now I understand why self.opaque = YES didn't work. Because you can use self only in instance of the class, not in the class function itself. try to call .opaque = YES on the instance of the LojaInfoHeaderView class, that you create in the viewForHeaderInSection function, that is add a pointer on your section header class there say LojaInfoHeaderView *header = [LojaInfoHeaderView lojaInfoHeaderForSection...]; header.opaque = YES; return header; See if this helps.